# qpython3, no codec search functions registered

Tags: android, python, qpython, qpython3

Recently tried installing qpython3 on my nexus 5x. Every time I try running anything I get a fatal python error "no code search functions registered". Based on everything I've seen about qpython and qpython3 I thought I'd be able to just install and go, but I know things with python are rarely that simple... Any help or tips would be greatly appreciated!